# VirtualBox 100 percent CPU usage

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox, cpu

I have MacOS as the host (`El Capitain`) and `Windows 7` as a guest - however the CPU rises up to 105 %, even when it is idle. I have searched the web, eventually found [this thread here on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/93484/virtualbox-cpu-usage-100-on-host), but have another configuration (Mac -> Win).
Is there some log I can provide to solve this (nerve-racking) issue?

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully someone finds it useful: in new laptops there are technologies that tell CPU how to work based on what power supply you have connected to it. So if you are using some unusual PS that you found at work etc, it might be hindering your CPU functions big time. 2 options:

1. Disconnect power supply and see how your virtual box works on just battery powered laptop. 
   -1a. consider changing your power plan in control panel.
2. There's a BIOS setting that would disable such behavior.

Comment: Are you able to provide some references for this?

Comment: https://blog.crsw.com/2013/02/08/dell-m4600-performance-improvement/ and https://blog.crsw.com/2013/02/08/dell-m4600-performance-improvement/

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include those links and the quote the relevant parts

Comment: The answer if sufficient for the problem it's addressing. The links are for your pleasure.

Comment: Please see [answer], my comments were intended to help you improve your answer.